# Recent posts with featured image or fallback image with permalink

Tags: php, images, post-thumbnails, array, recent-posts

In my sidebar.php I have some code that prints the recent comments.

I could not share the complete code here because of the formating restrictions. You can find the code here: https://codeshare.io/p8xjp

1. How can I display a custom fallback image (img from a directory) if the post does not have a featured image?
2. How can I lik the fallback images and featured images to the permalink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of your code that should work:

```
// This will make a URL like http://yoursite.com/path/to/fallback.png
$fallback_image = site_url( '/path/to/fallback.png' ); 
$fallback_image = "<img src='{$fallback_image}' />";

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){        
    echo '<div class="sidebar-entries">';
    $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent['ID'], 'sidebar-thumb', array( 'class' => 'sidebar-image' ) );

    if ( ! strlen( $featured_image ) ) {
        $featured_image = $fallback_image;
    }

    $permalink = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $recent['ID'] ) . '">%s</a>';

    echo sprintf( $permalink, $featured_image );

    echo '<div class="sidebar-entries-title">';
    echo sprintf( $permalink, __( $recent["post_title"] ) );
    echo '<div class="sidebar-date">';

    $timestamp = '<p>' . human_time_diff( strtotime( $recent['post_date'] ), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago </p>';
    echo sprintf( $permalink, $timestamp );
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The basic idea is

- Store your fallback image in a variable outside of your loop
- Get the featured image in the loop and store it in a variable
- If you get an empty string ( `! strlen()` )

  - Replace the contents of your featured image variable with the fallback image variable

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot about the permalink part. This approach uses `sprintf` to make your permalink code consistent.

Comment: Works like a charm! But what do you mean by storing outside the loop? Does that mean outside the wp-content folder?

Comment: @Arete "Outside the loop" refers to being defined outside of the `foreach` controls structure, or "loop". By storing `$fallback_image` outside of the `foreach`, the value only has to be defined once instead of each time the `foreach` iterates.